# Octave-Gui Help Command shows help page but doesn't respond to keystrokes

Tags: octave

I'm using version 4.03 of the Octave Gui on OS X (10.10.5 Yosemite).

I have a particularly annoying problem where if I run the help command on the command window, it will show a page of the Help Document and stop responding to any keystrokes afterwards (i.e. I can't go forward,back, quit etc)

The only way forward then is to press ctrl-c twice and kill Octave-Gui itself. Has anyone come across this or know a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I'm looking at the online help here.

https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/overview.html

Comment: press cursor up/down to navigate through the help pagen, press "q" to quit the pager

Comment: @Andy, those keys don't seem to work, I've already tried them before/after I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off the paging of the screen ouput by typing in the command 
***more off***

https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Paging-Screen-Output.html

Comment: it's a bad idea to turn off the pager for a help page, isn't it?

Comment: I guess that depends on how big the man page is and whether there is enough screen buffer to display it all in one go.